# Efficently copy i'th row of A lil matrix to j'th of B lil matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm facing a probleme. The folowing code works well but runs slow:
I have got 2 scipy LIL matrix one with value stored in and the ozer empty but with a specific shape

```
A.shape --> (X,Y)
B.shape --> (Y,Y)
with X < Y
```

and a paring dict

```
P = {X1:Y1 ....... X(X):Y(X)}
```

I'm doing

```
set process(A,B,P):
    for i in P.keys():
       B[P[i]]=A[i]
```

any idea how to make this process run faster ?

example :

```
A=[[1,2,3,4]
   [1,2,3,4]
   [1,2,3,4]]

B=[[0,0,0,0]
   [0,0,0,0]
   [0,0,0,0]
   [0,0,0,0]]

P={0:0,1:2,2:3}

in the end :

process(A,B,P)=[[1,2,3,4]
                [0,0,0,0]
                [1,2,3,4]
                [1,2,3,4]]
```

thank you !

Comment: So in dense array terms: `idx = [0,2,3]; B[idx,:] = A`

Comment: I feel stupid ! Thank you :)